# Proving existence of a cycle in a directed graph using Lovasz local lemma

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Let $D = (V, A)$ be a directed graph with minimum outdegree $\delta$ and maximum indegree $\Delta$. Prove (using
Lovasz local lemma) that, if  $k \le 1/(1+\ln(1+\delta\Delta))$, then $D$ contains a directed cycle of length divisible by $k$.

---

This question was asked in one of my class tests. My approach was that I was taking a subset $V'$ of vertices of length $p\times k$, $p$ is some constant greater than $0$ and creating a permutation sequence of these vertices. Then I was finding the probability of this sequence being a cycle. I am sure if I'm using the indegree and outdegree correctly also how to use Lovasz local lemma in this?

Comment: I have a question: if $\delta\Delta\geq2$, then $k<1$, so $k=0$ as $k$ should be a non-negative integer. But this seems weird. Perhaps the bound on $k$ is mis-typed here?

Comment: This is Theorem 6.3.1 in http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15850/handouts/matousek-vondrak-prob-ln.pdf

Comment: @Slugger The referred theorem has condition $k\le\frac\delta{1+\ln(1+\delta\Delta)}$, so the condition here is mis-typed.